# double border-style for table does not work

Tags: html, css

I noticed that when I apply a border-style to my table tag, it only works for solid, dashed or dotted, but it doesn't for double, groove and so on.

Is there a limitation for border-style for tables? Or am I doing something wrong?

```html
<table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse; 1px black; border-style:double;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="padding:5px; background-color:blue; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px">Pricelist</th>
            </tr>
        
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding:5px">Product</th>
                    <th style="padding:5px">Price</th>
                </tr>
        
            </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item1</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price1</td>
            </tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item2</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price2</td>
            </tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item3</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price3</td>
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you just left out "border: " in your html code. It should be "border: 1px black; border-style:double;" or you can write like this too. "border:1px black double;".

Comment: Get rid of the border-collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `1px black` into the property like, `border-width: 1px; border-color: black; border-style: double;` or just use `border: 1px black double;` to make it work. The `border="1px"` works "inside" the table, which you can set styles of `tr`, `td`, and `th` in css. I set different widths, 1px inside and 10px outside for you to see the differences clearly.

```html
<table border="1px" style="border: 10px black double;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="padding:5px; background-color:blue; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px">Pricelist</th>
            </tr>
        
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding:5px">Product</th>
                    <th style="padding:5px">Price</th>
                </tr>
        
            </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item1</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price1</td>
            </tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item2</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price2</td>
            </tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px">item3</td>
                <td style="padding:5px">price3</td>
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table border needs a "width."  Try..

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-style: double;
border-width: 4px;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Border Width is Too Small.

Specifying too small of a `border-width` will not allow for the `border-style` to be `double`. Essentially, it's too small to show two separate lines.

For example, if use something like `border-top: #333 double 1px;` then only a single line will be shown.

In fact, using `2px` for the width, like `border-top: #333 double 2px;`, will *still* not show a double line. Instead, it will just show a thicker, 2px-wide line.

I had to use at least `3px` for the double border to show properly, like `border-top: #333 double 3px;`.

This makes sense, considering it takes 3 pixels to show two 1px lines with a 1px gap between them.

```
1px (line) + 1px (gap) + 1px (line) = 3px
```

So your two options are:

1. Specify a bigger `border-width`, like `border-top: #333 double 3px;`.

   ***-or-***
2. Do not specify the `border-width`, like `border-top: #333 double;`, and let the browser/renderer figure it out.

Hopefully that helps others.